# Smarty (php). Вставить tpl файл (его содержимое) внутрь tpl файла

Tags: php, шаблоны, smarty

Например есть файл container.tpl

```
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Еще есть файл test.tpl

```
<div class="test">
</div>
```

А так же есть main.tpl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
{include 'container.tpl'}
//Как ставить в container test.tpl?
</body>
</html>
```

Чтобы получилось так

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="test">
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: обычно вроде на практике инклудят наоборот из файла контента подключают хэдер и футер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

**container.tpl**

```
<div class="container">
  {if $smarty.capture.content ne ''}
    {$smarty.capture.content}
  {/if}
</div>
```

**main.tpl**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  {capture name=content}
    {include file='test.tpl'}
  {/capture}

  {include 'container.tpl'}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: К сожалению нет.

Comment: Попробуйте тогда так

Comment: Спасибо за вариант :)